# Get trouble of Proxy issue when using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am having a weird issue where I have a proxy value added in my package.json file but when I am trying to connect with my server using axios, I see that my app gets directed to port 3000 which is the default path for react app.

my node.js server is running on port 5000.

I am using "concurrently" package to help run nodejs and react at the same time.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
"dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "gravatar": "^1.8.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.21",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^10.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}
```

```
// Use Routes
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/profile', profile);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
}
```

```
export const getCurrentProfile = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setProfileLoading());
    axios.get('/api/profile')
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.GET_PROFILE,
                payload: res.data
            })
        )
        .catch(err => dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.GET_PROFILE,               
            payload: {}
        }))
}
```

I expect the request url should be 'http://localhost:5000/api/profile', but I got 'http://localhost:3000/api/profile'.

Comment: Did you restart your server after adding the proxy?

Comment: yes, I did. Actually it worked yesterday. But when I continue to work on react, it suddenly crashed....

Comment: Okay i think i have found your issue?? do you have a `package.json` for both apps? or can you share the folder structure? or even your node/express server code too?

Comment: yes I do have package.json for both. I didn't change any code for the node/express, I can get proper response using postman.